# Gin. Assisted factory + GWT.create()

Tags: guice, gwt-gin

As far as I know GIN automatically uses GWT.create() fallback when there is no binding specified. It works perfect when a dependency is injected in a constructor.

```
@Inject
public PresenterImpl(ResourceManager manager) {...}
```

Is it possible to initialize the same object using assisted factory?
I have tried, but GIN fails to find proper "implementation".
In other words I want to define a factory module builder with interface that returns `ResourceManager` and initialize this object using factory.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose I'm not quite understanding what you want to do:

For an otherwise unspecified binding of, say, `ResourceManager`, GWT.create will be used, as you mentioned. However, you want to use a factory to perhaps *customize* the `ResourceManager` instance before being returned (e.g.: take a raw `GWT.create`'d ResourceManager, call some methods, and return it for use).

Here's what I might suggest in your Gin Module, instead of a factory:

```
@Provides
@MyCustomizedResourceManager
ResourceManager provideCustomResourceManager(ResourceManager basicResourceManager, Foo foo, Bar bar) {
  basicResourceManager.setFoo(foo);
  basicResourceManager.setBar(bar);
  return basicResourceManager;
}
```

The key difference is the customized binding: your provider method relying on the regular `GWT.create` call for the ResourceManager (and perhaps for Foo and Bar too), but the client (`@Inject MyClass(@MyCustomizedResourceManager ResourceManager manager`) relies on the binding you've set up explicitly.